# Why doesn't Django use select alias when filtering on an annotation?

Tags: sql, django, postgresql

Am I doing something wrong when filtering on an annotation based on a Subquery? Or why is not the alias used instead of computing the subquery again? Here is a dumb example that showcases my confusion

```py
Foo.objects.annotate(
    progress=Subquery(
        Job.objects.annotate(ps=Sum('progress')).values('ps')[:1], 
        output_field=IntegerField()
    )
).filter(progress__gt=0)
```

currently becomes

```sql
SELECT "foo"."id",

  (SELECT SUM(U0."progress") AS "ps"
   FROM "job" U0
   GROUP BY U0."id",
            U0."progress"
   LIMIT 1) AS "progress"
FROM "foo"
WHERE
    (SELECT SUM(U0."progress") AS "ps"
     FROM "job" U0
     GROUP BY U0."id",
              U0."progress"
     LIMIT 1) > 0
```

instead of simply

```sql
SELECT "foo"."id",

  (SELECT SUM(U0."progress") AS "ps"
   FROM "job" U0
   GROUP BY U0."id",
            U0."progress"
   LIMIT 1) AS "progress"
FROM "foo"
WHERE
    progress > 0
```

Comment: I've tested a similar scenario and got the same result, with postgresql_psycopg2 engine. In this case, does postgresql calculate the annotated field twice for each row, or does it understand that these are the same and calculate only once?